# visual studio debugging is ultimately slow in my Remote desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2010, virtual, remote-desktop, citrix

I am using visual studio 2010 in Remote desktop(citrix).Debugging is ultimately slow.
Previously I had Visual studio 2008 which is 5 times faster than this.

I found out that sometimes debugging become very faster in  2010 similar to Visual studio 2008 and most of the time very slow.I am not able to find out the reason behind this.
I think this may be due to some performance issue with my computer or Remote desktop.
Can you please suggest a solution.

Comment: If you are using remote desktop the problem is never on your local machine or with Remote Desktop (just displays what is happening on the (remote) server). The problem is caused by Citrix (the remote server where Visual Studio is being executed). Not enough resources (memory, cpu, processor time) for your process to execute.

Comment: Barry..Then how visual studio 2008 is running smoothly. If the problem is with the processor time or CPU ,can you suggest few solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a solution. I am no Citrix server configurator nor do I now the current configuration of the server park used. The only thing I do know is that your local machine and the remote session cannot cause this problem. You have to solve this problem with the responsible IT department.

Comment: OK..but do you have any idea..how it become faster sometimes and become slow after few days.

Comment: I see the same problem, and always blamed Citrix alone until I made the correlation with debugging. In my case, I'm debugging ASP(/.NET) apps, in VS2013. I've wondered if it's related to running a local IIS, and/or the new browser debugging feature. I've not tried debugging non-web apps.